# Can not declare a bytes32 fixed array or bytes32 unfixed array in a contract?

Tags: solidity

I tried to declare bytes32 array in a contract, it did not work.

```
 contract Demo{
        // compile error
        // TypeError: Type string memory[5] memory is not implicitly convertible 
        // to expected type bytes32[] storage ref.
        // bytes32[] public courseMap = ["Chinese", "English", "Math", "Computer", "Music"];
        // bytes32[5] courseMap = ["Chinese", "English", "Math", "Computer", "Music"];

        // compile error, the same as above
        bytes32[] public courseMap = ["Chinese", "English", "Math", "Computer", "Music"];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly cast the first element of the array literal to indicate the type. The Solidity compiler isn't smart enough to infer the right-hand side type for you:

```
bytes32[] public courseMap = [bytes32("Chinese"), "English", "Math", "Computer", "Music"];
```

Comment: Thanks, I understood.

Comment: It shows error: Type bytes32[5] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type bytes32[] memory.